# What is an easy way to work on an IPython Notebook hosted remotely?

Tags: ssh, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am ssh'd into a remote server would like to manipulate data on that machine without having to constantly push and pull the data around via my repository.

Can I run an IPython Notebook on that server and access/interact with it on my local browser? If so, how do I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html) will get you up and running if your server and your machine are on a LAN, and the server has one open port (there, 9999).

[This](http://wisdomthroughknowledge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/accessing-ipython-notebook-remotely.html) will make it work even if you only have ssh access to the remote server. It works with as an ssh tunnel with port forwarding.